# Apache vs Nginx for Chat Web App

Tags: apache, ubuntu, node.js, nginx

I want to implement a chat web application with Node.js & Socket.io. I'm currently using Apache as web server but I have heard that nginx can handle more requests with more concurrency than that of Apache because of the non-blocking nature of the system.

Will choosing Apache when I'm using Node.js & Socket.io will give me poor performance compared to choosing nginx?

If nginx is much better with Node.js & Socket.io, what is a good plan and a strategy to migrate my existing virtualhost file, extensions and pecls? I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 Natty on Amazon EC2.

Comment: Don't use either apache or nginx. Use node as your web server

Comment: But then.. I have to convert all my php codes to pure Javascript code right? I still want to use php.

Comment: @Raynos I know even mongoDB works better with Javascript because of its nature of using JSON.

Comment: why would you want to use php :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache is more flexable then Nginx but it comes with a high price in performance.
 With Nginx you need to think a little different so might be able to skip some of your extensions. The virtualhost-file does not exist in Nginx, it's all static in the config-file.

I recommend using Nginx with the [HTTP Push module](http://pushmodule.slact.net/). It's even supplied with a chat example.